# How can I send a UDP packet from bash and receive the response

Tags: bash, udp, netcat, socat

I want to send a UDP packet from bash (perhaps using netcat or socat) and then receive the one-packet reply, or time-out after three seconds.

(Strictly, the listening needs to start before the initial packet is sent.)

Is this possible, or do I need to write my own small C program?

---

- Netcat lets me either send *or* receive, so it won't do the job.
- Likewise for socat.
- Perhaps there is already a UDP request/response tool, but I don't know how to find it.

I need to write my own program for this use case.

Comment: The downvote means that we can't see any effort of your side in the question. For instance, we don't see what approaches you had tried by yourself. You could have for instance posted the`netcat` commands you have tried. It is also not clear whether you have problems with **sending** or with **receiving**.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks, I'll add the the question.

Comment: You could use `netcat` to start listening on the port you are expecting the reply, and in a separate process use `netcat` to send the request. Most likely, you will strat the listening netcat as a background process.

Answer (score 1):

Socats datagram mode works asynchronously. In particular, something like

```
socat -t 3 - UDP-DATAGRAM:localhost:7777,bind=:6666
```

might come near your requirements.